# Write a function that is an equation

Tags: python-3.x

I'm taking Intro to Programming this quarter, and we're doing Python. I'm working on an assignment, and I have been having trouble with it.

Here's what the assignment is asking...

Write a function called pq that, given values for the seven parameters listed below, computes the corresponding preparedness quotient PQ.

Here's the equation I must create:

PQ =  8*Pa(S + C) / 3*Pn(D + N + I)

Here's how the parameters must be ordered in the function header:

pq(i s c pn pa d n)

I = importance of event (1-10 with 10 being "singing national anthem at the Super Bowl")

S = number of hours of sleep you had last night

C = shots of espresso or other stimulants consumed

Pn = hours of preparation needed to excel

Pa = hours you actually spent preparing

D = difficulty of the subject matter (1-10 with 10 being "quantum physics")

N = level of nervousness (1-10 with 10 being "tightrope walking across Grand Canyon")

Here are some examples of how your function should work:

```
>>>pq(6,8,2,5,3,5,7)
```

0.8888888888888888

```
>>>pq(6,8,2,5,5,5,7)
```

1.4814814814814814

So far, this is what I've come up with...

```
def pq(i,s,c,pn,pa,d,n):
    denominator = 8 * pa * (s + c)
    numerator = 3 * pn * (d + n + i)
    return denominator/numerator

def main():
    i = float(input("On a scale of 1 to 10, what is the level of importance of the event: "))
    s = float(input("How many hours of sleep did you get last night? "))
    c = float(input("How many shots of espresso or other stimulants have you consumed? "))
    pn = float(input("How many hours of preparation are need to excel? "))
    pa = float(input("How many hours did you ACTUALLY spend preparing? "))
    d = float(input("On a scale of 1 to 10, what is the difficulty of the subject matter? "))
    n = float(input("On a scale of 1 to 10, how nervous are you? "))
    print ("Your prepardness qoutient is: " + (pq))

main()
```

I know the error is in print ("Your prepardness qoutient is: " + (pq)). I'm sure my code is all effed up, but I really have no idea what I'm doing, and mostly trying to emulate an example.  Basically I want to be able to input values, and with those value, end up with the PQ. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to convert `pq` into a string before printing it. Also, you need to pass it the appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't effed up. You are actually very close. You need to call the function pq. To call the function pq you must pass variables i,s,c,pn,pa,d, and n. A function call is a function name followed by (). main and pq are both examples of functions in your sample code.

```
prep_quotient = pq(i,s,c,pn,pa,d,n)
print ("Your prepardness qoutient is: %f"%(prep_quotient))
```

If you want to invoke the function pq from the python interpreter. Remove the function call to main from the python file. Save the file as pq.py. Go to the python interpreter. Then type the following.

```
>>>import pq
>>>pq.pq(6,8,2,5,3,5,7)
```

What is going on in this example?

When you type import module_name, Python looks for a file named module_name.py in the current folder you are in. An import loads all the variables and functions that you defined in your module. So if you import pq, then the interpreter loads in the function main and pq. You can then call the function pq that is in the module pq using the command

```
>>>pq.pq(6,8,2,5,3,5,7)
```

If you wanted to call the function named main in the module pq, you would type

```
>>>pq.main()
```

If you dont like typing pq.pq(), then in place of the line

```
>>>import pq
```

use the line

```
>>>from pq import pq
```

Then you can call the function pq directly.

```
>>>pq(6,8,2,5,3,5,7)
```

Comment: Oh wow!  Those % are new symbols to me.  I better go research what they are and how they work. I greatly appreciate the help.  Definitely pulled me off the cliff.

Comment: It turns out our teacher doesn't want the program to ask any inputs, he simply wants the program to execute like this:

>>>pq(6,8,2,5,3,5,7)

0.8888888888888888

How do i go about setting that up?